# User defined grid of numbers

Tags: python, string, printing

So I need to make a grid of numbers which is a grid of powers.
So the user enters 2 numbers and then the grid uses the indices and makes a grid.
if the user enters 5 and 5 it will display

```
1 1 1 1 1
2 4 8 16 32
3 9 27 81 243
4 16 64 256 1024
5 25 125 625 3125
```

but it needs to be right aligned so it displays the units in the 'units column'.
The gap is based on the length of the string denoting the highest number (32 is 2 characters long)
Basically, depending entirely on what the user enters but the gap has to decrease because the number gets longer. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Reference: http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language

Answer (score 1):

```
def pow_printer(max_val, max_pow):
    # What we are doing is creating sublists, so that for each sublist, we can
    # print them separately
    _ret = [[pow(v, p) for p in range(1, max_pow+1)] for v in range(1, max_val+1)]
    # The above produces, with max_val = 5 and max_pow = 5:
    # [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [2, 4, 8, 16, 32], [3, 9, 27, 81, 243], [4, 16, 64, 256, 1024], [5, 25, 125, 625, 3125]]

    # Now, we are looping through the sub-lists in the _ret list
    for l in _ret:
        for var in l:
            # This is for formatting. We as saying that all variables will be printed
            # in a 6 space area, and the variables themselves will be aligned
            # to the right (>)
            print "{0:>{1}}".format(var,
                                    len(str(max_val**max_pow))),  # We put a comma here, to prevent the addition of a
            # new line
        print  # Added here to add a new line after every sublist

# Actual execution
pow_printer(8, 7)
```

Output:

```
  1       1       1       1       1       1       1
  2       4       8      16      32      64     128
  3       9      27      81     243     729    2187
  4      16      64     256    1024    4096   16384
  5      25     125     625    3125   15625   78125
  6      36     216    1296    7776   46656  279936
  7      49     343    2401   16807  117649  823543
  8      64     512    4096   32768  262144 2097152
```

[Working example.](http://ideone.com/HBFUqw)

Answer (score 1):

This works fine (hope this is rather elegant and not too difficult to understand):

```
import math

def print_grid(x, y):
    # Get width of each number in the bottom row (having max values).
    # This width will be the column width for each row.
    # As we use decimals it is (log10 of the value) + 1.
    sizes = [int(math.log10(math.pow(y, xi)) + 1) for xi in range(1, x + 1)]
    for yj in range(1, y + 1):
        row = ''
        for xi in range(1, x + 1):
            value = pow(yj, xi)
            template = '%{size}d '.format(size=sizes[xi-1])
            row += template % value
        print row

print_grid(5, 5)
```

With the desired output:

```
1  1   1   1    1 
2  4   8  16   32 
3  9  27  81  243 
4 16  64 256 1024 
5 25 125 625 3125
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming you've already got the numbers you need, check out http://code.google.com/p/prettytable/ :

```
# Set up the number lists already
zz
[[1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 [2, 4, 8, 16, 32],
 [3, 9, 27, 81, 243],
 [4, 16, 64, 256, 1024],
 [5, 25, 125, 625, 3125]]

p = prettytable.PrettyTable()
for z in zz:
    p.add_row(z)

# Optional styles
p.align='r'
p.border=False
p.header=False

print p
 1   1    1    1     1
 2   4    8   16    32
 3   9   27   81   243
 4  16   64  256  1024
 5  25  125  625  3125

ps = p.get_string()
```